# Fix random seed for torchvision transforms

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, torchvision

I use some code similar to the following - for data augmentation:

```
    from torchvision import transforms

    #...

    augmentation = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomApply([
            transforms.RandomRotation([-30, 30])
        ], p=0.5),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
    ])
```

During my testing I want to fix random values to reproduce the same random parameters each time I change the model training settings. How can I do it?

I want to do something similar to `np.random.seed(0)` so each time I call random function with probability for the first time, it will run with the same rotation angle and probability. In other words, if I do not change the code at all, it must reproduce the same result when I rerun it.

Alternatively I can separate transforms, use `p=1`, fix the angle `min` and `max` to a particular value and use numpy random numbers to generate results, but my question if I can do it keeping the code above unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `__getitem__` of your dataset class make a numpy random seed.

```
def __getitem__(self, index):      
    img = io.imread(self.labels.iloc[index,0])
    target = self.labels.iloc[index,1]

    seed = np.random.randint(2147483647) # make a seed with numpy generator 
    random.seed(seed) # apply this seed to img transforms
    if self.transform is not None:
        img = self.transform(img)

    random.seed(seed) # apply this seed to target transforms
    if self.target_transform is not None:
        target = self.target_transform(target)

    return img, target
```

Comment: Thank you, `random` module works (not a surprise since I did not use it before) and images visually look the same with fixed seed, so both probability and random work with fixed results!

Answer (score 2):

Just complementing @conv3d answer. As it was put on this gh [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/42331#issuecomment-667434293). It is important to use two seed assignments together because not all transformations are unified.

```
random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
```

So the code would be like:

```
>>>
seed = np.random.randint(2147483647) 
random.seed(seed) 
torch.manual_seed(seed)
if self.transform is not None:
    img = self.transform(img)
<<<
```